# Core Data update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a project that has one to many relationships. I am trying to update Core Data. I have Core Data

[image]

To add, and update I use the code

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.contactdb) {
    // Update existing device
    [self.contactdb setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"name"];

   //------------- ???? --------------------

} else {
    // Create a new device
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"name"];

    for (int i = 0 ; i< appDelegate.TimeOfReceipt.count; i++) {

        NSManagedObject *timeinday = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Timeinday" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        TimeCell *p1 = [appDelegate.TimeOfReceipt objectAtIndex:i];

        [timeinday setValue:p1.dateOfTime forKey:@"timeinday"];
        [timeinday setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index"];
        [timeinday setValue:newDevice forKey:@"name"];

    }

}
NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

How do I update Timeinday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = твой контекст;

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name.name like[cd] %@",@"Нужный name у Name"];

NSEntityDescription *ed = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Timeindays" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:ed];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;


NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error requesting items from Core Data: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [context deleteObject:managedObject];
}

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@", ed, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Или просто

```
//Выбери нужный Name, потом: 

for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in name.timeinday) {
    [context deleteObject:managedObject];
}

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@", ed, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: I have a record in CoreData and I need to change the values ​​in it. I can change the name. But the values ​​timeinday not.

Comment: Im improve my answer.

Comment: I may change the number of elements.

Comment: Мне надо поменять значения взяв их из appDelegate.TimeOfReceipt но значений в массиве может стать больше или меньше чем было когда создавалась новая запись.

Comment: Короче нужно чтобы количество Timeinday сущностей у Name сущности было равно количеству appDelegate.TimeOfReceipt? Верно?

Comment: Можно при изменении массива выбрать Name сущность, затем удалить все ее Timeinday, затем пересоздать их.

Comment: я пробовал вот так [[self.contactdb valueForKey:@"timeinday"] removeAllObjects]; это работает до того момента как повторно запускаешь приложение после повторного запуска все возвращается обратно.

Comment: После этого создай сколько тебе нужно. Повторяй при изменении размера массива. Если ты таблицу заполняешь из coredata и у тебя есть делегат таблицы, ты бы мог создать M штук Timeinday для каждого Name, и в методе делегата поставить ограничение на количество строк - не больше чем длина массива appDelegate.TimeOfReceipt .

Comment: Так они все удаляются а не только в выбранной Name.

Comment: Ахаха, я по контексту подумал что у тебя только 1 Name. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Нижний кусок тоже должен работать, если я не путаю.

Comment: Сам с coredata мучаюсь в настоящий момент. Рад был помочь.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off creating managed object subclasses in Xcode as it will add a number of suitably typed methods that you can use when integrating with to-many relationships. Then, use those methods instead of `setValue:forKey:`.

In your case, while you should do that, your relationship is 1:to-many so you can set the 1 end instead:

```
[newDevice setValue:timeinday forKey:@"timeinday"];
```